# How do I make ALL drop-down lists hidden in Sharepoint Wepart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, accordion

I have a webpart that would be used for a FAQ page on our website. There will be a lists with titles (questions) and below them the answers. My accordion list of questions displays fine and when clicked displays the answers.

My issue is the very first list is always selected when navigating to the page and a user would need to unselect it to hide it. How do I make all the lists hidden?

I've used and modified my html code from [JQuery](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible).

```
<!doctype html> 

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `active: false`

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false
    });
  } );
```

Comment: You're a life saver Lee, thank you :)